# Transferring 3 SQL databases from both SQL Server 2005 Express and Standard to a new physical server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-express

I am trying to figure out the best method for transferring SQL Server 2005 databases from 2 different physical servers to a new server running Windows Server 2008 64bit.

I own a fully registered copy of Microsoft SQL Server 2005 32bit Standard Edition. However all of my SQL Server databases together are only 4GB in size thereby making SQL Server 2008 Express an option.

Here is the breakdown of the servers:

1. (Old Server1) Windows 2003 Server 32bit - SQL Server 2005 Express 32bit
2. (Old Server2) Windows 2003 Server 32bit - SQL Server 2005 32bit Standard
3. (New Server) Windows 2008 Server 64bit - (Not sure which version to install)

The objective is to migrate the 2 SQL Server databases from Old Server1 and 1 SQL Server database from Old Server 2 to the New Server. What version should I install on the new server? Do I go with SQL Server 2008 Express or install the SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition?

Pending your response to which version to install, what are the correct steps to migrate (which I have never done before) the databases from both of these servers to the new server?

I have researched this online and I think this particular situation is unique in that I am transferring from both SQL Server Express and Standard from 2 different physical servers to a 2008 server that is 64bit. I cannot find anything online that I feel confident in trying. Please help me, as I have this migration deadline of this weekend. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Please look for another place to ask this question.

Comment: You simply backup the databases from the source servers and restore them into the new SQL Server. Not much more to it really. Bitness (32/64) is irrelevant unless you are using some funky linked servers (i.e. connecting to external Excel). If you're certain your DB's will not grow beyond 10G in the medium term then why not go the whole and try SQL 2014 Express. Its MAX size is 10G!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: SQL Server **2005** is *no longer supported* by Microsoft. Do you *really* want to migrate *to an unsupported* version of SQL Server? Also: if ever possible, move to a **more recent** version - SQL Server **2014** Express is just as free as the 2008 version - and it supports databases up to **10 GB** (the limit was upped from 4 to 10 GB with SQL Server **2008 R2** Express) ....

Comment: To add to someone else's comments, see if you can BACKUP the 2005 DBs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865(v=sql.90).aspx). move the backup files to the new server, and restore them through SSMS.